# VSE - Scale image on both X and Y axis

Tags: transforms, video-sequence-editor

I am editing a video in blender and I have to scale a lot of images to fit certain sizes in the image. I noticed that to scale an image in the transform panel, I can only change one axis at the time, and to make the image ratio correct I have to constantly match the y axis scale to the new x axis scale. This is very slow and gets bothersome rather quickly.

Is there a way to change both axes at the same time?

[image]

Comment: click in x and keep holding down mouse button, then drag down to y -> enter value -> both values will be changed

Comment: @Chris wow this works perfectly! Didn't know you could do this, thanks! You can even drag both values together with the mouse for fine adjustments

Comment: Glad I could help